# Using current instance of Internet Explorer for GetObject

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, sendkeys

I am trying to use SendKeys to navigate & enter data with Internet Explorer. The first section of code has a loop during which the webpage (ending in .php) refreshes itself to get the entry in. As I'm using SendKeys once the browser is opened, I'm looking for a way to pause the script until the page is loaded and ready to receive input. I'm currently using a small time delay of 3 seconds which works well but if the browser lags, everything goes haywire.

So, is there anything that can facilitate this or at least allow me to use the GetObject command to set a current instance of Internet Explorer as an object.

```
    AppActivate "Explorer"
    Dim CCount As Integer
    Dim DCount As Integer
    Dim LCount As Integer
    LCount = 1
    CCount = 2
    DCount = ActiveSheet.Range("O2").Value
    Dim LoopP As Integer
    LoopP = 1
    For LoopP = 1 To DCount


    SendKeys ActiveSheet.Range("A" & CCount).Value, True
    SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    SendKeys Format(ActiveSheet.Range("C" & CCount).Value, "#,###"), True
    SendKeys "{Tab}", True

' Breakdown IF
    If ActiveSheet.Range("K" & CCount).Value = 1 Then
    SendKeys ActiveSheet.Range("D" & CCount).Value, True
    Else
    End If

    SendKeys "{Tab}"

' Remark IF
    If ActiveSheet.Range("L" & CCount).Value = 1 Then
    SendKeys ActiveSheet.Range("E" & CCount).Value, True
    Else
    End If


    SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    SendKeys "{Enter}", True
    CCount = CCount + 1

'    While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
'    While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
'    Do While IE.readyState <> 4: WScript.Sleep 100: Loop
     Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Next LoopP
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add your code into the question itself. Off-site links usually disappear after some time and then the question becomes useless for further readers.

Comment: Oh okay, didn't realise, will do next time on!

Comment: I'd recommend against using send keys.  As you've seen, there is no way to synchronise your calls against the target.  Instead, you can create an [instance of IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970672.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in VBA.  You will then be able to monitor the progress of page loads etc.

Comment: I ended up doing that, works like a charm!